# Arraylist in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, arraylist

In the code below there is a inparameter named thumbs to the function CreatePage. thumbs is an arraylist. My question is if you know if it's possible to split the arraylist thumbs into parts of 15 and call the function with thumbs(1-15), thumbs(16-30), thumbs(31-45) and so on. Until the arraylist is empty.

```
html.CreatePage(txtTitleTag.Text, txtText.Text, "index", txtDirectory.Text & "\", thumbs,  txtMetaDesc.Text, txtMetaKeywords.Text, "test.com", "test2.com",  BackgroundColor, FontColor)
```

Comment: What version of .NET are you using? If it's not 1.1 (I really doubt it is) then you should not be using an `ArrayList`.

Comment: What type of object is in the `ArrayList`? `String`s?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, switch from an `ArrayList` to a `List(Of String)`. `ArrayList` was already outdated in .NET 2.0, and you'll benefit a lot from strong typing.

Next, here's a method to chunk a `List`:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function Chunk(Of T)(ByVal this As List(Of T), ByVal length As Integer) As List(Of List(Of T))
    Dim result As New List(Of List(Of T))
    Dim current As New List(Of T)

    For Each x As T In this
        current.Add(x)

        If current.Count = length Then
            result.Add(current)
            current = New List(Of T)
        End If
    Next

    If current.Count > 0 Then result.Add(current)

    Return result
End Function
```

Now, just use a `For Each` loop that iterates over the chunks:

```
For Each chunk As List(Of String) In myList.Chunk(15)
    'Call the function and pass chunk as an argument
Next
```

Voilà!